# How to use 2.5D on openalyers 3?

Tags: openlayers-3, 2.5d

I would like to enable 2.5D (and not 3D) on a map created with OpenLayers 3. Each tile is supplied from a Geoserver.

The web app using this map is very specific and is running on a Firefox Browser.

I've searched all the way across the Internet (my journey was long), and I've found nothing relevant regarding this issue. I couldn't even find if this is possible with OpenLayers 3 or not.

So here's my question : is it possible to do such a thing, and if so, how ?

EDIT: we cannot use WebGL due to the hardware limitations of our equipments.

Comment: You have normal 2D tiles and want to render a 2.5D effect on top of these tiles?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to do :)

Comment: OpenLayers  3 doesn't support this out-of-the box. But there seem to be [experiments](https://github.com/kekscom/osmbuildings/commit/c3be6183af3f8867ce791d7fa087e3aeb8ee0eb8) to add support for [OSM Buildings](http://osmbuildings.org/) to ol3.

Comment: Hi @tsauerwein, thanks for your answer, I see that the classic version of OSMBuildings does not require WebGL, which is nice in this case. I'll try to make a PoC with OpenLayers to see if the integration matches our expectations.

Comment: @tsauerwein After some research, OSMBuildings will be unlinkely used, as we will not be allowed to use OSM. I guess there is no way we could do this, unless our equipment supports WebGL.